# The AppFabric Caching Service service terminated unexpectedly

Tags: 2013, distributedcache, app-fabric

The event viewer of the WFE server recieves errors regarding the AppFabric Caching Service:

> 1. AppFabric Caching service crashed with exception
> 2. {6d304b9000000000000000000000000} failed to refresh lookup table, exception: {Microsoft.Fabric.Common.OperationCompletedException: Operation completed with an exception ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
> 3. Faulting application name: DistributedCacheService.exe, version

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this problem is due to permissions issue on the config DB, SO

- Ensure that the AppFabric service identity has the appropriate access
  to the farm configuration database.  Mapping it to the SPDataAccess
  role is sufficient.

Check this blog for the troubleshooting.

[SharePoint 2013: AppFabric service repeatedly stops](http://alstechtips.blogspot.com/2015/04/sharepoint-2013-appfabric-service.html)

Comment: Hi , i added serviceaccount to SPDataAccess database role in sharepoint_config database, but still in one of wfe server appfabric cache service did not started, when i start it started but suddenly it is again started mode.

Comment: when i use Get-CacheHost  it status showing WFE2.xxx.com:2233  and service status: down

Comment: are you starting the app fabric service from services console or from SharePoint central admin.